# Google Analytics page views javascript vs event tracking javascript

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

Currently, I have a standard google analytics snippet that counts page views:

```
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');
  ga('create', 'UA-xxxxxxxx', 'example.com');
  ga('send', 'pageview');
```

However, I would now like to add event tracking to some elements on my website and for that I need to add this tracking code as suggested by GA:

```
  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXX-X']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();
```

My question: do I need to replace the original code with the tracking code, or should I have both scripts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google FAQ wasn't very clear about it, but it turns out there are two javascript libraries for google analytics `analytics.js` and `ga.js`, where `analytics.js` is a new library and `ga.js` is an older library, but both providing the same service.

So to use tracking with `analytics.js` you don't need to include any extra snippets, but make sure that the tracking APIs you are using are for the newest library

[Upgrade: ga.js to analytics.js](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/upgrade/reference/gajs-analyticsjs)

[Event Tracking (analytics.js)](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events)